# Extra argument 'error' in call - do/catch?

Tags: swift

I know there is new error handling i.e. do/catch but not sure if it applies here and even if it does it's pretty difficult for me even going through the documentation. Could someone show me the correct code block please.

```
     /*** error Extra argument 'error' in call ***/
    var plistDic = NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(plistData!, 
    options:Int(NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.MutableContainersAndLeaves.rawValue), 
    format: nil, error: &error) as Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> 

    assert(error == nil, "Can not read data from the plist")

    return plistDic
} 

   // END
```

EDIT:

```
let YALCityName = "name"
let YALCityText = "text"
let YALCityPicture = "picture"

private let kCitiesSourcePlist = "Cities"

class YALCity: Equatable {

var name: String
var text: String
var image: UIImage
var identifier: String

// MARK: Class methods
class internal func defaultContent() -> Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(kCitiesSourcePlist, ofType: "plist")
    let plistData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)
    assert(plistData != nil, "Source doesn't exist")


    do {
        let plistDic = try NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(plistData!,
            options:NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.MutableContainersAndLeaves,
            format: nil
        )

        if let dictionary = plistDic as? Dictionary< String, Dictionary<String, String> > {

            print("\(dictionary)")

        }
        else {

            print("Houston we have a problem")
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }


        return defaultContent()

}



init(record:CKRecord) {
    self.name = record.valueForKey(YALCityName) as! String
    self.text = record.valueForKey(YALCityText) as! String
    let imageData = record.valueForKey(YALCityPicture) as! NSData
    self.image = UIImage(data:imageData)!
    self.identifier = record.recordID.recordName
}

}

func ==(lhs: YALCity, rhs: YALCity) -> Bool {
return lhs.identifier == rhs.identifier
}
```

Comment: Looks like the swift version of that method is defined as `throws` and does away with the `error` parameter. This is a very common pattern for cocoa APIs in Swift 2, there's a lot of info about this (starting by Apple's documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
do {
    var plistDic = try NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(plistData!,
         options:NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.MutableContainersAndLeaves,   
         format: nil
         )

    // plistDic is of type 'AnyObject'. We need to cast it to the
    // appropriate dictionary type before using it.

    if let dictionary = plistDic as? Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>> {
        // You are good to go.
        // Insert here your code that uses dictionary (otherwise
        // the compiler will complain about unused variables).
        // change 'let' for 'var' if you plan to modify the dictionary's
        // contents.

        // (...)
    }
    else {
        // Cast to dictionary failed: plistDic is NOT a Dictionary with
        // the structure: Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>
        // It is either a dictionary of a different internal structure,
        // or not a dictionary at all.  
    }
}
catch let error as NSError {
    // Deserialization failed (see console for details:)
    print(error)
}
```

Note: I split the call to a function that throws (`try...`) and the casting to your specific type of `Dictionary` (`if let...`) because I'm not really sure exactly what would happen if the call succeeds but the cast fails, or if it would be clear which one failed from the debugger. Also, I don't like too many things happening in one line...

**EDIT:** I fixed the `options` parameter. In Swift, `Int`s and `enum`s aren't interchangeable; you need to pass the right type (I missed it the first time when modifying your code).

Comment: Just the place where you call NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData().

Comment: See my edit. I tried the new code in my environment (Xcode 7.1) and it compiles.

Comment: That is because you are not using `dictionary` (my code says "you are good to go", assumes your code using that variable follows). You should put your logic (where you operate on `dictionary`) there. See my latest edits